# How do I make the elements on my navbar stack on top of one another when the screen gets smaller?

Tags: html, css

How do I make the elements in my navbar stack on top of each other when, say, someone is using a phone or resizes the screen? It works a little bit for me already, in the sense that only the last element in my navbar goes below the others when it is made smaller, but it is the only one to go down, the rest of the elements just stay in place for some reason. Here's my code:

```css
body {

        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

    }

    nav {

        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
        margin: .4em auto;
        background-color: white;
        overflow: hidden;

    }

    nav ul {

        padding: 0%;
        position: relative;
        margin: .5em auto;
        list-style: none;


    }

    nav ul li {

        width: 15%;
        margin: 0 .5%;
        margin-left: 3%;
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;

    }

    .logo img {

        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }


    nav a {

        width: 100%;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5%;
        font-size: 3em;

    }

    #navbar ul li a:hover {

    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(173, 12, 7);
    color: white;


}
```

```html
<nav>

<div class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="CSS/logo.jpg" id="logo" width="250" height="150"></a></div>

<div style="width: 1100px; margin: 0 auto;">

<div id="navbar">

    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
    <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>

</div>

</nav>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap or anything? Or are you writing your own css? This will be useful to know to accurately answer your question.

Comment: @MichaelBuchok By looking at the CSS I believe OP is writing their own CSS and not using any CSS frameworks

Comment: Yes, I am writing my own CSS.

Comment: Have you tried the css property `flex-wrap: wrap` or alternatively `wrap-reverse` ? From what you wrote that might help. At least I use it to stack items when shrinking the size of the screen

Comment: maybe you want : `<div style="width: 1100px; margin: 0 auto;">` being `<div style="max-width: 1100px; margin: 0 auto;">`  and `nav ul li {width: 15%;}` be  `nav ul li {min-width: 15%;}` ?

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti Thanks genius, just making sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading your question I inferred that, you want a navbar elements to stack one by one when screen width reduces, if so this way you can do it, but this is not how navbar works. I would recommend you the second way (scroll past this snippet)

Both solution uses css flexbox properties such as `display: flex`, `flex-wrap: wrap` and the second solution uses the property `flex-direction: column`

First solution:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100vw;
}

#navbar > ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;

}

a {
  color: black;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

#navbar > ul > li:hover > a{
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div style="width: 1100px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div id="navbar">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="/logo.jpg" id="logo" width="70" height="70">
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
      <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>

</nav>
```

But would recommend you this way, which uses media query to properly illustrate the navbar when the breakpoint is reached, here font size is kept 1em and media breakpoint added as 400 px for mobile screens

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100vw;
}

#navbar > ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;

}

a {
  color: black;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

#navbar > ul > li:hover > a{
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #navbar {
    align-items: center;
  }
  .logo {
    text-align: center;
  }
  #navbar, #navbar > ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 200px;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div style="width: 1100px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div id="navbar">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="/logo.jpg" id="logo" width="70" height="70">
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
      <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>

</nav>
```

Comment: Ok, one of the comments at the top solved my problem, but I think that this might be better to use, so thanks.

Comment: One question though, what does #nabar > ul do?

Comment: It means that it will apply the styling to the immediate child `ul` of the element having id as a navbar. Have a look at this official documentation of selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors